# How to add more than 4 quick action items in UIApplicationShortcutIcons(3D touch) in iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I am working on 3D touch features in iOS. I want to add more than 4 shortcut items. I go through apple documentation which states that

> iOS 9 displays up to four Home screen quick actions for your app

But the **soundhound** application is showing 5 items(more than 4 items) in their application. So I am very curious to know how **soundhound** is achieving the same thing. 
I tried to add all the items dynamically but it reject the last one in the array.
I also tried to add static items in info.plist but the same result.

Any help is highly appreciable.

I am adding the screenshort of the sound hound application just for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Last one looks like sharing button. Maybe it's some special kind of button? Beside that - no idea.

Comment: The last one is added by the OS to all apps you download from the app store, you can add 4 of your own.

Comment: So after releasing my app with 4 different shortcut items, iOS has added 5 "share" option automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You can add only upto 4 Shortcut Items (static/dynamic).

The `Share <#AppName#>` will be added default if the application downloaded from appstore.